# Keep getting this error Error: Cannot find module './config.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Here is the error that I get every time I try to execute the code and I can't find a solution so please help.

```
PS C:\Users\boble\OneDrive\Desktop\ScriptsNStuff\karmik> node .
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './config.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\boble\OneDrive\Desktop\ScriptsNStuff\karmik\commands\Test.js
- C:\Users\boble\OneDrive\Desktop\ScriptsNStuff\karmik\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\boble\OneDrive\Desktop\ScriptsNStuff\karmik\commands\Test.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\boble\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ScriptsNStuff\\karmik\\commands\\Test.js',
    'C:\\Users\\boble\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ScriptsNStuff\\karmik\\index.js'
```

Comment: Simple. Either the file does not exist or you're providing the wrong filepath

Comment: I know the file is completely 100% correct but how do i make sure im providing the correct file path

Comment: Your console disagrees. It would not be throwing an error if the filepath was valid

Comment: Hmmm, can u help me i will send all the code/things you need ive been working on this for a while.

Comment: Yes go ahead. For future reference always include all of the information needed. The most important thing to show for this question would be your folder tree

Comment: Ok so lets start off with my config.json
```{
 "prefix": ">",
 "token": "My token"
}```

Comment: Oh i figured it out my code was just garbage and i had to recode it